# VPN Connection between Windows Server 2008 and a Cisco ASA

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, cisco-asa

Is there a windows software VNP equivalent to OpenSwan for Linux?

Requirement: Establish a secure connection with a third party provider to consume a service.

Currently, I have a Linux box with OpenSwan, and I am trying to setup a vpn connection between the server and a Cisco ASA firewall. Phase 1 completes successfully, but Phase two doesn't. However this is another problem for another question.

In this case, I have a client in the same scenario but he works exclusively on windows azure so I need to setup a secure vpn connection between a windows server and the same Cisco ASA device. Windows Connect is not an option because I have no control on the customer gateway, the Cisco Device is administered by a thrid party offering a service.

Is there something that might help me do this? To be honest my knowledge on the subject is slim. In the first scenario I am using a tutorial I found in the web, but my linux/openswan/vpn knowledge is limited.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco provides VPN software for windows clients.  Is this not an option for your setup?

Comment: You mean client vpn software? The thing is, the third party requested that we use physical hardware to connect to them, which we do not have (we are on the cloud), So I need to use something that is transparent to them. Would the Cisco vpn software you mentioned work in this situation?

Comment: I need something like a virtual router of sorts...